# What does "psz" stand for in pszBuffer or the similar?

Tags: c

I know it is a little bit off topic but I believe I can get the answer anyway here. What does "`psz`" stand for in `pszBuffer` or the similar variable in C/C++ system library? I saw a lot of variables prefixed with "`psz`" and it looks like a pattern.

Thanks!

Comment: See [Hungarian Notation Reference](http://www.cse.iitk.ac.in/users/dsrkg/cs245/html/Guide.htm).

Comment: That hideous affront to programming-kind known as Hungarian notation. Kill it! Kill it with fire!

Comment: @GregS, Hungarian notation can be very useful when done [right](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Wrong.html).

Comment: actually real hungarian notation is very good, where the prefix described the semantics, not the syntax of a variable; useful in a non typed language like C. But it got corrupted into the syntax mess by people who did not understand the original intent. By non-typed I mean that you cannot create a type for columnNumber or width, etc.

Comment: @ikegami: Read it, I'm not convinced, and not only will I not use but I hate hate hate hate hate reading any code that uses at all, in any way, ever.

Comment: @GregS, I've found it useful in a couple of places, mostly to avoid name collisions. e.g. `$foo_text` (text) vs `$foo_utf8` (encoded text), `$foo_pat` (regex pattern) vs `$foo_re` (compiled regex pattern), `$foo_fh` (file handle) vs `$foo_fn` (file base name) vs `$foo_qfn` (file qualified name), etc. But it's not just to avoid name collisions. In some cases, though, it seems many people are incapable of comprehending that there is a difference without resorting to annotation.

Comment: @ikegami: The hungarian notation that I know and hate uses prefix letters. As a suffix it is acceptable. Don't ask my why I have that reaction, I just do.

Comment: @GregS: So you going into conniptions when you have to use `fopen`, `fclose`, `fread`, `strlen`, `strcpy`, ...?

Comment: Is it true that Apple uses this?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This is [*Hungarian notation*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation).  `psz` normally stands for "(**p**)ointer to (**s**)tring, (**z**)ero-terminated".

Comment: actually if you read the history of Hungarian notation it is not that. It is 'twisted hungarian notation'

Answer (score 6):

Pointer_to_String_terminated_by_Zero

Comment: Using underscores *and* a mix of camel and Pascal case nicely emphasizes the horror.  Couldn't have come up with that myself, I have to say.

Comment: Err.. all my C++/Delphi code has camel-case and a two/three letter prefix that describes the variable/object/class.  Have I been writing obfuscated code for all this time?  (I have weaned myself off the underscores - the C/C++ compilers add plenty of underscores on their own:).

Comment: @MartinJames Probably not. It's more subjective than most people want to admit.

Answer (score 6):

**P**ointer to **s**tring, **z**ero terminated.

It is known as Hungarian notation which is something that tends to stir up strong feelings amongst programmers!

Answer (score 0):

none of the answers explained what it means.

the main important fact is that it is a variable for a pointer on a string that has ending by NUL or 0x00 by default. also expressed via: '\0' (the zero value of course)

however could also mean:
that the pointer is having NUL by default and points on a string.
either way you can find out for sure if you just filter for NUL testing towards the pointer address and value and towards the string value involved.

this should clarify it!

Comment: Well, from what I read, **all three** of the other answer explain what the 'psv' prefix means (some better than others - but all better than you).